# Clear a frame from videoView, Twilio Video

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiview, twilio

I am using [Twilio Video Swift Quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift)

I am rendering a video track (for a video call) using UIView that conforms to class [TVIVideoView](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.1/docs/Classes/TVIVideoView.html#//api/name/initWithFrame:delegate:).

When the video call ends, I am hiding videoView, when the call is about to start again, I am unhiding the videoView which displays the last frame from previous call. 
**How can I clear the frame of previous call from videoView ?**

The below is what I am doing, to start and stop rendering the video track.

```
// To start rendering videoTrack
videoTrack.addRenderer(self.videoView)

// To stop rendering videoTrack
videoTrack.removeRenderer(self.videoView!)
```

`videoTrack` conforms to class [TVIVideoTrack](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.1/docs/Classes/TVIVideoTrack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not an iOS expert, but I do have a couple of ideas here.

Firstly, rather than hiding and showing the `videoView` could you teardown and recreate it each time. Then there won't be any residual frames left on it.

Alternatively, you could create a `TVIVideoRenderer` compliant class that simply produces blank frames and use that as an in between renderer while the `videoView` is hidden.

Let me know if that helps at all.